# Parsing a large complicated patent classification XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to parse a large file in particular the English version of the https://www.wipo.int/ipc/itos4ipc/ITSupport_and_download_area/20200101/MasterFiles/index.html, a classification of patents in XML format. I am new to XML parsing so I think that is why I'm having a hard time parsing elements I really want from this file.

Let me provide some context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IPCScheme xmlns="http://www.wipo.int/classifications/ipc/masterfiles" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" edition="20200101" lang="EN" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.wipo.int/classifications/ipc/masterfiles ipc_scheme_3-1.xsd">
  <ipcEntry kind="s" symbol="A" entryType="K">
    <textBody>
      <title>
        <titlePart>
          <text>HUMAN NECESSITIES</text>
        </titlePart>
      </title>
    </textBody>
    <ipcEntry kind="t" symbol="A01" endSymbol="A01" entryType="K">
      <textBody>
        <title>
          <titlePart>
            <text>AGRICULTURE</text>
          </titlePart>
        </title>
      </textBody>
    </ipcEntry>
    <ipcEntry kind="c" symbol="A01" entryType="K">
      <textBody>
        <title>
          <titlePart>
            <text>AGRICULTURE</text>
          </titlePart>
          <titlePart>
            <text>FORESTRY</text>
          </titlePart>
          <titlePart>
            <text>ANIMAL HUSBANDRY</text>
          </titlePart>
          <titlePart>
            <text>HUNTING</text>
          </titlePart>
          <titlePart>
            <text>TRAPPING</text>
          </titlePart>
          <titlePart>
            <text>FISHING</text>
          </titlePart>
        </title>
      </textBody>
.
.
</ipcEntry>
.
.
</IPCScheme>
```

You can assume that the file is perfectly formatted, each branch has complete closure. It is quite long ~800,000 lines which is why I'm refraining from attaching the whole file in this code sample.

A short overview of the hierarchy should show that is is like:

1. ROOT
2. level 1: Symbols {A,B,C,D,E,F,K}
3. level 2: Subdivisions in each symbol {A01, B22 etc.}
4. level 3: further subdivisions

And this goes on till about H05K0013040000, the largest layer of granular complexity.  In some of them, it halts till about level 5 but the reason why the sample isn't closed is because of these further subdivisions in between.

### The task

I would like to extract textual descriptions from this patent classification file for example in the sample provided I would like to extract `HUMAN NECESSITIES` or `AGRICULTURE`. You can assume that all these subdivisions have  in them and most of them are dominated by this hierarchy at this level (that is `<title>` -> `<titlePart>` -> `<text>`)

### Using `lxml` in Python

Here is a sample code of what I've been trying to do:

```
from lxml import etree
import lxml

tree = etree.parse('EN_ipc_scheme_20200101.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for elem in root.findall(".//*[@kind='s']"):
    body = elem.find('textBody/title/titlePart/text')
    print(body)
```

My output is

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work :)

```
from lxml import etree
import lxml

tree = etree.parse('EN_ipc_scheme_20200101.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root.iter():
    if element.text != None:
        print("%s" % (element.text))
```

output:

```
HUMAN NECESSITIES
AGRICULTURE
AGRICULTURE
FORESTRY
ANIMAL HUSBANDRY
HUNTING
TRAPPING
FISHING
SOIL WORKING IN AGRICULTURE OR FORESTRY
PARTS, DETAILS, OR ACCESSORIES OF AGRICULTURAL MACHINES OR IMPLEMENTS, IN GENERAL
making or covering furrows or holes for sowing, planting or manuring 
machines for harvesting root crops 
mowers convertible to soil working apparatus or capable of soil working 
mowers combined with soil working implements 
soil working for engineering purposes 

... (continued very long had to interrupt)
```

Although you might change the code from printing on console to rather saving in a text file. That would save the result. Might take some time to write all of it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is exactly what I was looking for in my problem (will probably push it to CSV)!

Answer (score 1):

The namespace of every entity in the XML example you have shown falls under `xmlns="http://www.wipo.int/classifications/ipc/masterfiles"`. You can see this by looking at the children of root.

```
root.getchildren()
# returns:
[<Element {http://www.wipo.int/classifications/ipc/masterfiles}ipcEntry at 0x210f93ab288>]
```

The http path in the curly brackets is the namespace.  To search, you have to specify the namespace you are searching within.  Normally you can just append the name of the namespace to the front of your path elements and pass in the namespace as a dictionary, like this:

```
root.findall('xs:textBody', namespaces=ns)
```

The issue is that this namespace is not tagged, so it appears in the namespace map under the key `None`.

```
root.nsmap
# returns:
{None: 'http://www.wipo.int/classifications/ipc/masterfiles',
 'xhtml': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
 'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
```

As a simple work-around, you can replace the `None` key with a key of your choosing, then reference that key in searches.  Below, you can refer to the default namespace as `'z'`.

```
ns = xml.nsmap
ns['z'] = ns.pop(None)

for elem in root.findall(".//*[@kind='s']", namespaces=ns):
    body = elem.find('z:textBody/z:title/z:titlePart/z:text', namespaces=ns)
    print(body.text)
# prints:
HUMAN NECESSITIES
```

Alternativly, you can search through all namespaces using `{*}` before each path element.

```
for elem in root.findall(".//*[@kind='s']"):
    body = elem.find('{*}textBody/{*}title/{*}titlePart/{*}text')
    print(body.text)
# prints:
HUMAN NECESSITIES
```

Comment: This is a great and descriptive answer. You go in-depth on what's wrong with this file! If I had the option of voting correct answer on both I would vote for yours as well and I generally recommend to people who view this question to read this answer very carefully!